# How to force linebreaks in kableExtra functions with escape = FALSE?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

In kableExtra >= 0.8.0, [the canonical way](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf) to insert a linebreak into text piped into a table from a kableExtra function such as `add_header_above` or `pack_rows` is to add an `\n` directly.

However, this appears not to work with the `escape = FALSE` argument, which is required if the text also contains LaTeX code.

How can one force linebreaks in kableExtra functions with `escape = FALSE`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

starwars %>%
  filter(species == 'Gungan' | species == 'Droid') %>%
  arrange(species) %>%
  select(name, eye_color) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  pack_rows(
    index = c(
      'The droids: everybody\'s favourite' = 6, 
      'The Gungans: only beloved of \nthose aged under $3^2$' = 3), 
    escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: Should the output be pdf or html? (in html you could actually use <br/> to force the break)

Comment: As it happens, I'm compiling to PDF, but (as I haven't specified that in the question) the correct solution should be something that works for both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ISSUE

The issue at hand is that you wish to escape part of your header (i.e., the break) and not escape another part (i.e., the math code).

#### Further Complications

This core issue is further complicated by a number of factors:

1. when and how kableExtra is programmed to deal with escaping
2. a desire to have a solution that works for both html and LaTeX output
3. when and how R evaluates code

### A SOLUTION

Here is a solution that will work for both html and LaTeX output, but it is not as clean and straight forward as your original code:

```
# a new version of `kableExtra::linebreak()` that takes into account what type 
# of output is desired as well as how much escaping is necessary
linebreak2 <- function(x, double_escape = TRUE, ...) {
  # if LaTeX insert text into a `\makecell[]{}` command and double escape
  if(knitr::is_latex_output())
    return(linebreak(x, double_escape = double_escape, ...))
  
  # if html output just replace `\n`s with `<br/>`s
  if(knitr::is_html_output())
    return(gsub("\n", "<br/>", x))
  
  # let x pass through for other types of output
  return(x)
}

# build the index named vector outside the pipe flow 
# in order to set the names using `linebreak2()`
index <- c(6, 3)
names(index) <- c(
  'The droids: everybody\'s favourite',
  linebreak2('The Gungans: only beloved of \nthose aged under $3^2$')
)

# proceed as before
starwars %>%
  filter(species == 'Gungan' | species == 'Droid') %>%
  arrange(species) %>%
  select(name, eye_color) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  pack_rows(index = index, escape = FALSE)
```

#### PDF Output

[image]

#### HTML Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That does the trick!!! Enjoy your bounty. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `html` line break tag `<br/>`:

```
starwars %>%
  filter(species == 'Gungan' | species == 'Droid') %>%
  arrange(species) %>%
  select(name, eye_color) %>%
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  pack_rows(
    index = c(
      'The droids: everybody\'s favourite' = 6, 
      'The Gungans: only beloved of <br/> those aged under $3^2$' = 3), 
    escape = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works when rendering to HTML -- as one would expect, given that <br/> is an HTML tag. When rendering to PDF, the tag appears as text in the rendered table itself.